# iphone programming obj-c : removing the "..."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

when you enter a too long sentence for the iphone it automaticaly add a "..." at the end to show you there is other stuff you don't see right. I want to delete those "...".

image : 
[alt text http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/2159/screenshot20100602at095.png](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/2159/screenshot20100602at095.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm assuming you're using a label. Look into the "lineBreakMode" property. Your solution will probably involve some combination of that property in conjunction with the "numberOfLines" property. For example, setting the "numberOfLines" property to 0 will automatically increase the height of a label to fit all text.  So using that with a UILineBreakModeWordWrap would probably do the trick.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.text = @"Light beer 5% 10oz Glass served cold";
[label release];
```

Comment: ok thanks, i don't understand totally what you said but i need to reduce the text size to fit the tableview cell. how to i put numberoflines property to 0 ?

Comment: ok i almost got it , my tableview cell is filled with a string, how can i do it to fill with a label?

Comment: ok it works guys thanks but it tell me a warning... 'deprecated"

Comment: You're likely set cell's text as cell.text = @"blabla" - that's deprecated method and you should use cell.textLabel.text = @"blabla" now. (or set string value to any other cell's labels)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options for that:

1. Set label's lineBreakMode property to UILineBreakModeClip - that way your sentence will just be clipped without "..." on the end
2. Set label's adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property to YES - label will automatically reduce font size to fit string into available space
3. Make your UILabel have multiple lines - set its `numberOfLines` property to 0 and lineBreakMode to UILineBreakModeWordWrap. Although with this approach your label's height must be big enough to contain several lines...